# How to create an abstract function to reduce code duplication

Tags: ios, swift

I have a few functions that are basically the same apart from a few variable names that they reference. I want to abstract the function so that I don't have to keep duplicating the code. This is an example function:

```
func listenToParticipantNumber() {
    guard let reference = participantNumberReference else {
        return
    }
    guard participantNumberListener == nil else {
        return
    }
    participantNumberListener = backendClient.listenToRtdbProperty(reference) { [weak self] (result: Result<Int, RequestError>) in
        guard let strongSelf = self else {
            return
        }
        switch result {
        case .success(let participantNumber):
            strongSelf.participantNumber = participantNumber
        case .failure:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

In another function, I'd switch out `participantNumberReference`, `participantNumber`, and `participantNumberListener` for different variables (which are all private to my class), and the block return type of `Int`. But the core layout of the function would be the same.

How can I make this process cleaner to reuse this code rather than having to duplicate it? Is it possible to somehow use `KeyPaths` to reference different variables of my class?

Comment: Try Using protocol-oriented programming and use protocol extensions to give the function a default implementation and you can conform to the protocol to any class and use the functions as it is.

Answer (score 0):

It takes a lot of pre-amble to achieve this abstraction level, so you have to ask larger questions about What You're Really Trying To Do, and Is It Worth It, but here's an outline. The essence is to *use a dictionary with properties* instead of explicitly declared variables.

Now you can add future cases to `PersonType` and initialize them (which may be automate-able) and the function will apply to all of them regardless. `PersonType` could conceivably be declared outside the class to increase separation.

This is probably a better suited for Code Review, where you can post a lot more context.

```
enum PersonType { case Participant, case Leader, case Observer }
struct TrackedObject { var number: Int; var numberReference: ReferenceProtocol; var numberListener: ListenerProtocol; }
// Instead of 9 private variables, make a Dictionary of 3 objects each of
// which have 3 properties
private var persons: [ PersonType: TrackedObject ] = ...

func listenToPersonOfType(personType: PersonType) {
    guard let reference = persons[personType].numberReference else {
        return
    }
    guard persons[personType].numberListener == nil else {
        return
    }
    persons[personType].numberListener = backendClient.listenToRtdbProperty(reference) { [weak self] (result: Result<Int, RequestError>) in
        guard let strongSelf = self else {
            return
        }
        switch result {
        case .success(let number):
            strongSelf.persons[personType].number = number
        case .failure:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right road with a KeyPath. I would probably refactor this a little bit so that the `listen` method returns `Listener?` (whatever type that is), and hoist the "if listener is already set, don't do this," outside of this function.

That would leave you something along these lines:

```
func listen<Response>(reference: Int?,  // Or whatever type this is
                      updating keyPath: WritableKeyPath<C, Response>,
                      completion: (Result<Response, Error>) -> Void) -> Listener? {

    guard let reference = reference else { return nil }

    return backendClient.listenToRtdbProperty(reference) { [weak self] (result: Result<Response, Error>) in
        guard var strongSelf = self else {
            return
        }
        switch result {
        case .success(let result):
            strongSelf[keyPath: keyPath] = result
        case .failure:
            break
        }
}
```

Or you can keep your existing structure with something like this:

```
func listen<Response>(reference: Int?,
                      updating keyPath: WritableKeyPath<C, Response>,
                      forListener listener: WritableKeyPath<C, Listener?>,
                      completion: (Result<Response, Error>) -> Void) {

    guard let reference = reference else { return }

    guard self[keyPath: listener] == nil else {
        return
    }

    var mutableSelf = self
    mutableSelf[keyPath: listener] = backendClient.listenToRtdbProperty(reference) { [weak self] (result: Result<Response, Error>) in
        guard var strongSelf = self else {
            return
        }
        switch result {
        case .success(let result):
            strongSelf[keyPath: keyPath] = result
        case .failure:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

(`C` in all of this code is "this class." We can't yet write `Self` to mean "the current class.")

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it like this:

```
private func listen<T>(
    to property: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<LivestreamModel, T?>,
    withReference propertyReference: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<LivestreamModel, String?>,
    listener: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<LivestreamModel, DatabaseHandle?>) {
    guard let reference = self[keyPath: propertyReference] else {
        return
    }
    guard self[keyPath: listener] == nil else {
        return
    }
    self[keyPath: listener] = backendClient.listenToRtdbProperty(reference) { [weak self] (result: Result<T, RequestError>) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let value):
            self?[keyPath: property] = value
        case .failure:
            self?[keyPath: property] = nil
        }
    }
}
```

I actually did this before Rob replied, but I had to use `ReferenceWritableKeyPath` because it gives a warning that `self` has no subscript members when using `WritableKeyPath`.